# Scheduling DAG to run every 45 minutes in Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG that needs to be scheduled to run every 45 minutes (00:00, 00:45, 1:30, 2:15 etc.)
How do I do this in Airflow.
Plain cron entry for this looks as below:

0,45  0-23/3 * * *

30    1-23/3 * * *

15    2-23/3 * * *

How do I schedule the DAG with above cron entries.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`schedule_interval` just supports one cron expression.

I see two options:

- Having 3 DAGs, one for each cron expression. DAGs could be created dynamically by iterating over the cron expressions.
- Running the DAG every 15 minutes and usage of `PythonBranchOperator` ([Airflow Documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#branching)) to decide if the time matches one of the 3 cron expressions. I used [croniter](https://github.com/kiorky/croniter) package in the past for matching airflows `execution_date` against different cron expression